# Twenty seventeen header is not responsive

Tags: headers, responsive, theme-twenty-seventeen

Hello the header of my Twenty Seventeen website is not responsive: when I open the site on my mobile phone (vertical view) the image is cropped. When in horizontal view everything is ok. All other images are ok.
I have been trying for days to fix this but I am not able. Can you help me?
Thanks
Anna Mombelloni

Comment: Responsive doesn't mean uncropped. The Twenty Seventeen header is not designed to keep the exact same shape across all screen sizes.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you suggest me some similar theme designed to keep the exact shape? Thank you